# Code reuse Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, reusability

I am working in a project targeting Windows Phone 8. What is the best approach to reuse code from this project? The goal is to reproduce similar projects that will have common ui and functionality. I want to change some colors, some translations and a bit of the logic. Is possible to change only some parts of my project? From the web search I found many resources of how to reuse code and target multiple platforms (Windows 8, Windows Phone 8, etc). My use case is a little different. I have already a project and want multiple copies with small changes and the main logic in common.

Comment: Extract your logic into other project(s). Create a class library and move your code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract your logic into other project(s).

**1. Create a new `Class Library` project.**

Two files will be created: a default class file `Class1.cs` and the assembly manifest `AssemblyInfo.cs`, which contains metadata about the code library.

**2. If you want to write or move code to your library:**

From the `Project` menu, choose `Add New Item` to add the appropriate new item (control, component, class, and so on) and then move/write the appropriate code.

**3. Reference the newly created library to your projects.**

In references menu of your WP8 projects select `Add new reference` and choose the newly created library.

Comment: So can i have AppResources.resx file in the Class Library with the common translations and add second AppResources.resx in each project with unique translations ?

Comment: Sure you can. Give it a try! :)